# NHibernate is not connecting to sql server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, nhibernate, connection

When i set up a regular connection, it works, however when i try to use nhibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml, i m getting the following error.

*Message="A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"
   Source=".Net SqlClient Data Provider"*

What would be the reason for this and how can i resolve it ?

I doubt that it s a network or sql server configuration error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=(ServerName\DEV_ENV);Initial Catalog=dbName;User Id=SA;Password=PASS</property>

    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu</property>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: And what is in your hibernate.cfg.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to connect to the server with the same connection string, but with another data access technology, for example pure ADO.NET.

If that fails as well, then it's not a NHibernate problem.
Maybe your connection string or some SQL server settings are not correct, as indicated in the error message:

*"Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."*

Comment: i have tried all these crap,nothing worked. i guess hibernate doesnt work :)

Comment: What does "nothing worked" mean? Did you try to connect to the database with pure ADO.NET with the same connection string, and did it work? If no, then it can't be a NHibernate problem.

Answer (score 3):

Is your connection string correct?

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005

Comment: does it look wrong? it should be correct. and even though i tried other formats still same crap.

Comment: Nice link. For other versions of SQL Server connection string use this [link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) and pick you version from the "Connect to" menu on the right.

Answer (score 2):

This is the format i have used for over a dozen applications for SQL SERVER 2005/2008

```
data source=COMPUTERNAME;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;database=DATABASENAME
```

or if you require an instance name

```
data source=COMPUTERNAME\SERVERINSTANCE;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;database=DATABASENAME
```

replace the placeholders in capital letters.
Also ensure that you have set up sql-server to allow connections for `Sql Server Authentication` and not only `Windows Authentication`.
Check your firewall as well

Comment: THanks man, i tried this format, didnt wanna work. but ADO.NET works.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a small piece of code in the same application to open a raw ado.net connection with the same connection string and it worked.

Then and I copy pasted that connection string into the configuration file for nhibernate and it started working.

When I compared the original string giving the error and the new connection string... I couldn't see any difference whatsoever... no clue what's going on... totally stumped... anyways the problem's solved... hope this helps someone.